# How to you measure lines of front-end code (HTML, CSS, JS, JSP)?

Tags: html, windows, metrics, codebase, lines-of-code

The company I work for is being audited and I have to provide some metrics on our codebase.

I have provided some statistics on our Java code using some plugins for Eclipse.

But I also need to measure lines of front-end code: HTML, CSS, JS, JSP.

Is there a (Windows) tool that would help with this?

Comment: If you are measuring lines of code their wasting their time with this. Lines of code dont mean much of anything as adding or removing lines of code could be good or bad, introduce errors or remove them. I'd be very interested in what kind of metrics your actually providing them with?

Comment: n4rzul: for me it's a measure of whether I did anything a day or not. And if, what I did (coding/commenting/writing). I don't know what benefits you were talking about exactly. Just because I can count lines of code doesn't mean I have to use them as a metric for developer productivity.

Answer (score 0):

for getting code metrics of javascript inside JS and HTML you can use [ProjectCodeMeter](http://www.projectcodemeter.com) (it will give you LOC, constants, complexity, arithmetic and even development time), but for CSS and HTML markup i don't know any measurement tool, when i think of it, these are mostly generated by editors like DreamWeaver or CMS templates, so they're not really "lines of code"...